# On activeadmin dashboard, trying to show only events in the future

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

On Activeadmin I have an events_date table. On the dashboard I am trying to show only upcoming event dates. I am having trouble figuring out how to do this. This is the code I have so far:

```
     column do
       panel "Upcoming Events" do
         table_for EventDate.order("event_date asc").limit(20), sortable: true do
           column :event_date

           column "Event Name" do |event_date|
                     event_date.event_location.event.name
                   end   
           column "Agency Id" do |event_date|
                     event_date.event_location.event.agency_id
                   end             
           end
         end
       end
     end
```

As you would guess this gives me all my event dates. How can I get it to only show me dates in the future from today?

Comment: The code looks ok. I'm not sure I have seen a panel nested inside a column before but I don't think that's an issue. How many records is it rendering is it more than 20?

Comment: Yes, the code works and gives me all the events. However, I want only future events to be shown. So if the event date was yesterday or in the past, I don't want it to show.

Answer (score 1):

You can use arel_table to get a greater than or eq to Time.zone.now query.

```
class EventDate > ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :future, -> { where(arel_table[:event_date].gteq(Time.zone.now)) }
  # another way of doing it  
  scope :future, -> { where("event_date >= ?", Time.zone.now) } 
end 

# active admin 

table_for EventDate.future.limit(20), sortable: true do
  column :event_date

  column "Event Name" do |event_date|
    event_date.event_location.event.name
  end   

  column "Agency Id" do |event_date|
    event_date.event_location.event.agency_id
  end             
end


# Should give this query 
EventDate Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "event_dates".* FROM "event_dates" WHERE "event_dates"."event_date" >= '2017-03-22 13:39:38.427240'
```

Comment: Not sure hope to implement that code. I put it under ActiveAdmin.register_page "Dashboard" do
however I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: scope :future should be in the EventDate model.